# Porting WordPress Gutenberg to a Standalone React Component - CSS Styles Not Appearing

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm attempting to create a standalone version of Wordpress' [Gutenberg](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg) block editor that will work independently of the Wordpress ecosystem. Ideally, I'd like to be able to simply use the Gutenberg editor in an existing React project as a React component.

I noticed the official repository featured a "storybook" directory which housed a React component at "**storybook/stories/playground/index.js**":

```
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
import "@wordpress/editor"; // This shouldn't be necessary

import { useEffect, useState } from "@wordpress/element";
import { BlockEditorKeyboardShortcuts, BlockEditorProvider, BlockList, BlockInspector, WritingFlow, ObserveTyping } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { Popover, SlotFillProvider, DropZoneProvider } from "@wordpress/components";
import { registerCoreBlocks } from "@wordpress/block-library";
import "@wordpress/format-library";

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import "./style.scss";

function App() {
    const [blocks, updateBlocks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        registerCoreBlocks();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="playground">
            <SlotFillProvider>
                <DropZoneProvider>
                    <BlockEditorProvider
                        value={blocks}
                        onInput={updateBlocks}
                        onChange={updateBlocks}
                    >
                        <div className="playground__sidebar">
                            <BlockInspector />
                        </div>
                        <div className="editor-styles-wrapper">
                            <BlockEditorKeyboardShortcuts />
                            <WritingFlow>
                                <ObserveTyping>
                                    <BlockList />
                                </ObserveTyping>
                            </WritingFlow>
                        </div>
                        <Popover.Slot />
                    </BlockEditorProvider>
                </DropZoneProvider>
            </SlotFillProvider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default {
    title: "Playground|Block Editor"
};

export const _default = () => {
    return <App />;
};
```

This looked like a perfect candidate to modify into a standalone component, so I modified it slightly so it would function in a new **create-react-app** project:

```
import React from "react";
import "@wordpress/editor"; // This shouldn't be necessary

import { useEffect, useState } from "@wordpress/element";
import { BlockEditorKeyboardShortcuts, BlockEditorProvider, BlockList, BlockInspector, WritingFlow, ObserveTyping } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { Popover, SlotFillProvider, DropZoneProvider } from "@wordpress/components";
import { registerCoreBlocks } from "@wordpress/block-library";
import "@wordpress/format-library";

import "./style.scss";

export default function App() {
  const [blocks, updateBlocks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    registerCoreBlocks();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="playground">
      <SlotFillProvider>
        <DropZoneProvider>
          <BlockEditorProvider value={blocks} onInput={updateBlocks} onChange={updateBlocks}>
            <div className="playground__sidebar">
              <BlockInspector />
            </div>
            <div className="editor-styles-wrapper">
              <BlockEditorKeyboardShortcuts />
              <WritingFlow>
                <ObserveTyping>
                  <BlockList />
                </ObserveTyping>
              </WritingFlow>
            </div>
            <Popover.Slot />
          </BlockEditorProvider>
        </DropZoneProvider>
      </SlotFillProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I saw the component referenced a "**style.scss**" file (which in turn referenced 'editor-styles.scss' and 'reset.scss') so I copied those files into my new React project as well:

[image: React project src directory]

I saw in the "package.json" file in the Gutenberg repository that all of the Wordpress dependencies were being referenced via a "packages" directory, e.g.:

```
"@wordpress/babel-plugin-import-jsx-pragma": "file:packages/babel-plugin-import-jsx-pragma",
"@wordpress/babel-plugin-makepot": "file:packages/babel-plugin-makepot",
"@wordpress/babel-preset-default": "file:packages/babel-preset-default",
"@wordpress/base-styles": "file:packages/base-styles",
```

So I copied the "packages" directory from Gutenberg into my new React project and then added all of the Wordpress dependencies to my "package.json" file:

```
    "dependencies": {
            "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
            "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
            "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
            "@wordpress/a11y": "file:packages/a11y",
            "@wordpress/annotations": "file:packages/annotations",
            "@wordpress/api-fetch": "file:packages/api-fetch",
            "@wordpress/autop": "file:packages/autop",
            "@wordpress/blob": "file:packages/blob",
            "@wordpress/block-directory": "file:packages/block-directory",
            "@wordpress/block-editor": "file:packages/block-editor",
            "@wordpress/block-library": "file:packages/block-library",
            "@wordpress/block-serialization-default-parser": "file:packages/block-serialization-default-parser",
            "@wordpress/block-serialization-spec-parser": "file:packages/block-serialization-spec-parser",
            "@wordpress/blocks": "file:packages/blocks",
            "@wordpress/components": "file:packages/components",
            "@wordpress/compose": "file:packages/compose",
            "@wordpress/core-data": "file:packages/core-data",
            "@wordpress/data": "file:packages/data",
            "@wordpress/data-controls": "file:packages/data-controls",
            "@wordpress/date": "file:packages/date",
            "@wordpress/deprecated": "file:packages/deprecated",
            "@wordpress/dom": "file:packages/dom",
            "@wordpress/dom-ready": "file:packages/dom-ready",
            "@wordpress/edit-post": "file:packages/edit-post",
            "@wordpress/edit-site": "file:packages/edit-site",
            "@wordpress/edit-widgets": "file:packages/edit-widgets",
            "@wordpress/editor": "file:packages/editor",
            "@wordpress/element": "file:packages/element",
            "@wordpress/escape-html": "file:packages/escape-html",
            "@wordpress/format-library": "file:packages/format-library",
            "@wordpress/hooks": "file:packages/hooks",
            "@wordpress/html-entities": "file:packages/html-entities",
            "@wordpress/i18n": "file:packages/i18n",
            "@wordpress/is-shallow-equal": "file:packages/is-shallow-equal",
            "@wordpress/keyboard-shortcuts": "file:packages/keyboard-shortcuts",
            "@wordpress/keycodes": "file:packages/keycodes",
            "@wordpress/list-reusable-blocks": "file:packages/list-reusable-blocks",
            "@wordpress/media-utils": "file:packages/media-utils",
            "@wordpress/notices": "file:packages/notices",
            "@wordpress/nux": "file:packages/nux",
            "@wordpress/plugins": "file:packages/plugins",
            "@wordpress/priority-queue": "file:packages/priority-queue",
            "@wordpress/redux-routine": "file:packages/redux-routine",
            "@wordpress/rich-text": "file:packages/rich-text",
            "@wordpress/server-side-render": "file:packages/server-side-render",
            "@wordpress/shortcode": "file:packages/shortcode",
            "@wordpress/token-list": "file:packages/token-list",
            "@wordpress/url": "file:packages/url",
            "@wordpress/viewport": "file:packages/viewport",
            "@wordpress/wordcount": "file:packages/wordcount",
            "concurrently": "^5.0.2",
            "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
            "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
            "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.4.0",
            "node-watch": "^0.6.3",
            "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
            "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
            "react": "^16.12.0",
            "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
            "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
            "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
            "@wordpress/babel-plugin-import-jsx-pragma": "file:packages/babel-plugin-import-jsx-pragma",
            "@wordpress/babel-plugin-makepot": "file:packages/babel-plugin-makepot",
            "@wordpress/babel-preset-default": "file:packages/babel-preset-default",
            "@wordpress/base-styles": "file:packages/base-styles",
            "@wordpress/browserslist-config": "file:packages/browserslist-config",
            "@wordpress/custom-templated-path-webpack-plugin": "file:packages/custom-templated-path-webpack-plugin",
            "@wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin": "file:packages/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin",
            "@wordpress/docgen": "file:packages/docgen",
            "@wordpress/e2e-test-utils": "file:packages/e2e-test-utils",
            "@wordpress/e2e-tests": "file:packages/e2e-tests",
            "@wordpress/env": "file:packages/env",
            "@wordpress/eslint-plugin": "file:packages/eslint-plugin",
            "@wordpress/jest-console": "file:packages/jest-console",
            "@wordpress/jest-preset-default": "file:packages/jest-preset-default",
            "@wordpress/jest-puppeteer-axe": "file:packages/jest-puppeteer-axe",
            "@wordpress/library-export-default-webpack-plugin": "file:packages/library-export-default-webpack-plugin",
            "@wordpress/npm-package-json-lint-config": "file:packages/npm-package-json-lint-config",
            "@wordpress/postcss-themes": "file:packages/postcss-themes",
            "@wordpress/scripts": "file:packages/scripts"
    },
```

Then ran "npm i" so that my React application could reference the Wordpress packages via import statements.

Now, when I run "npm start", the React application will launch in my browser, and the Gutenberg editor will be present, but none of the CSS/styles work:

[image: Gutenberg Editor without CSS Styles]

I'm not entirely sure how to proceed. The application seems to function as desired (I can create, edit, and remove blocks), but the styles simply aren't present.

I attempted to compile the existing scss files (in the **src**, **node_modules**, and **packages** directories) via the following commands in packages.json:

```
"build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules --include-path ./packages src packages node_modules -o src --recursive --watch",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules --include-path ./packages -o src --watch"
```

But the resulting **style.css** file, when imported to my **index.html** file, didn't seem to change anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you investigated the styling of your objects by right-clicking in the browser and choosing the Inspect option?  That feature of browser devtools can tell you a lot about the CSS applied to each object.

Comment: @rudy are you still using this? Does it still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that there was another **style.scss** file in the **storybook** directory which, when placed into the root directory of my React application, along with updating the package.json scripts to:

```
"build-css": "node-sass-chokidar style.scss -o public/css",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path node_modules style.scss -o public/css --watch"
```

The styles were compiled correctly.

Comment: Do you have a repo somewhere with this working?